# How to use vba for sumif function( data consolidation)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, consolidation, vba

Hi I have a data set like this:

```
    A  B
    a  2
    b  1
    c  3
    a  1
    b  2
```

I Want to the consolidated data on column D and E that the duplicates are removed. Example below.

```
   Eg. 
    D  E
    a  3
    b  3
    c  3
```

I have figured out removing duplicate part. But I am still stuck on consolidation. I reckon using Sumif can solve the problem. But Iam not sure this is the best solution.
Can anybody help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using the implemented features will surely be the best solution in my opinion.

So:

```
Sub Consolidate()

 With ActiveSheet

  .Columns("A:B").Copy Destination:=.Columns("D:E")
  .Columns("D:E").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
  lLastRow = .Columns("D").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  .Range("E1:E" & lLastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C[-4],RC[-1],C[-3])"

 End With

End Sub
```

Or simply using `Consolidate`

```
Sub Consolidate2()

 With ActiveSheet

  .Range("D1").Consolidate Sources:="C1:C2", Function:=xlSum, _
        TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False

 End With

End Sub
```

Note, the `Sources:="C1:C2"` is given in R1C1 notation. So it means Column1 to Column2.

Comment: Thanks. It works! I adopted the first one. I have tried the data consolidation method. but it was giving me issue.